# CAML Query for Person or Group Field using email ID c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm having a people picker column in SharePoint list, i want to get items having specific users in people picker column. But i'm having only Email id of a person so how to get items using email id. I'm using below query.

`camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' LookupId='TRUE' />" +"<Value Type='User'>"+ EmailID + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";`

But its not giving me a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't query the people picker column directly using email id, as a work around i have used below steps.

1. Get user email id
2. pass email id to

````
    web.SiteUsers.GetByEmail(EmailID);```
 3. Now in getUser object we get user display name. Pass that display
    name to caml query.

```camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name'/>" +"<Value Type='Text'>" + getUser.Title + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";```
````